# zen of angular2 universal - when to app.browser.module.ts or app.node.module.ts

Tags: angular, angular-universal

In angular2 universal....the docs are 2 files

```
app.browser.module.ts
app.node.module.ts
```

https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

Both on a fresh repo look the same.  I assume one is for server side (node) and other is for client side (browser)?

So when I am adding routes, imports etc I am adding to both because I am unsure what do to.  If I have to add to both then why 2 files that look the same?

When would I add to one or the other where the diverge?  When do I add to both node and browser app?

Thanks

app.browser.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal/browser'; // for AoT we need to manually split universal packages

import { App, Home } from './app/app';

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  declarations: [ App, Home ],
  imports: [
    UniversalModule, // BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule are included
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: Home, pathMatch: 'full' }
    ])
  ]
})
export class MainModule {

}
```

app.node.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal/node'; // for AoT we need to manually split universal packages

import { App, Home } from './app/app';

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  declarations: [ App, Home ],
  imports: [
    UniversalModule, // NodeModule, NodeHttpModule, and NodeJsonpModule are included
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: Home, pathMatch: 'full' }
    ])
  ]
})
export class MainModule {

}
```

Comment: rather stunned that the angular-universal team does not even  take a stab at answering the question.  Even there home home page is out of date and provides wrong setup info.

Comment: To answer your `"rather stunned that the angular-universal team does not even take a stab at answering the question. Even there home home page is out of date and provides wrong setup info."` I think the team is busy impleting Universal since it is very new. They need balance time creating new things and helping people. I would suggest if you want something be improved, create a PR [here](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues) instead complaining here

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:
https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md

Note that in the starter repo app.node.module.ts and app.browser.module.ts are exactly the same, but in your app they will almost certainly be different as you specify node-only or browser-only providers in the imports section as appropriate for each specific platform.